# how to use std::threads efficiently to reduce run time

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

My code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
  thread t[10];
  for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    t[i] = thread(print,i);//thread creation
  for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    t[i].join();//waiting maiin to threads to cpmleate execution
  cout << "in main";
}

void print(int i) {
  cout<<"i:"<<endl;
}
```

Is this the most efficient way, or is there a more efficient way to get less run time?

Comment: For such a simple example as this, it will probably be slower, because you have the overhead of first creating the threads, then the OS have more threads to switch between. But the biggest bottleneck here is the output. Output is generally (comparatively) slow, doing from multiple threads may not speed it up.

Comment: How is your current run time? Is it significantly slower than what you have expected? Do you think there is something in your current code that you suspect is not giving you the most efficient results?

Comment: The code shown can never benefit from adding threads. The threads must wait for each other to write to `cout` (note that usually you'd have to do explicit synchronization, but the standard gives some specific guarantees in case of `std::cout`).

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to do a much more complicated job with the threads. The amount of speedup you can get by multithreading depends on your problem, and not all kinds of problems can be parallelized. There are several books about this topic if you really want to explore it deeply. Multithreaded programming is not an easy thing, and there are a lot of caveats you have to beware of. Some basic rules of thumb:

- Use number of threads equal to the number of processor cores you have. Having much more have no advantage.
- Minimize the amount of shared data between threads. Optimally, each thread should work on independent data, so there is no synchronization overhead. It is usually impossible, but you should use as few synchronization as possible.
- When using synchronization, minimize the time a mutex is locked.
- To avoid deadlocks, always have a certain order of mutexes to lock. For example, if you lock mutex B after you locked A, then never have any place where you lock A after B.

There are many others, these are just the tings immediately came to my mind.

Comment: 'Use number of threads equal to the number of processor cores you have. Having much more have no advantage' - wrong.

Comment: @MartinJames Could you please elaborate why?

Comment: you missed out the word 'ready': ''Use number of ready threads equal to the number of processor cores you have. Having much more have no advantage'.  If the threads are I/O bound, eg. stuck on network, the optimnal number of threads to use will be many more than the number of cores.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency for parallelization depends on multiple factors (by far non exhausive list):

- How can your problem be split into subproblems?
- How do the subproblems depend on each other (requiring synchronization)?
- What is the limiting factor of your problem, is it CPU, memory, disk...?
- ...

Looking at your code: The `thread` class of C++11 is normally used for lower level implementations, e.g. implementing a thread pool. For your problem, higher level methods, like `async()` or `run_once()` might be more applicable.

If you are really interested in the subject, you should acquire a good book on the subject, e.g. "C++ concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams (he is on SO as well)